# what is difference between these two syntax in my code

Tags: javascript, regex

What is difference between The following syntaxs in regular expression?

Please give an example.

```
(?=.*\d)
```

and

```
.*(?=\d)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is *just* an assertion, a positive look-ahead saying "there must be zero or more characters followed by a digit." If you match it against a string containing at least one digit, it will tell you whether the assertion is true, but the matched text will just be an empty string.

The second one searches for a match, with an assertion (a positive-lookahead) after the match saying "there must be a digit." The matched text will be the characters before the last digit in the string (including any previous digits, because `.*` is greedy, so it'll consume digits up until the last one, because the last one is required by the assertion).

Note the difference in the match object results:

```js
var str = "foo42";
test("rex1", /(?=.*\d)/, str);
test("rex2", /.*(?=\d)/, str);

function test(label, rex, str) {
  console.log(label, "test result:", rex.test(str));
  console.log(label, "match object:", rex.exec(str));
}
```

Output (for those who can't run snippets):

```
rex1 test result: true
rex1 match object: [
  ""
]
rex2 test result: true
rex2 match object: [
  "foo4"
]
```

Notice how the match result in the second case was `foo4` (from the string `foo42`), but blank in the first case.

Answer (score 1):

`(?=...)` is a [*positive lookahead*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Both of these expressions will match "any text followed by a number". The difference, though, is that `(?=...)` doesn't "eat" ("capture") any characters as it matches. For practical purposes, if this is the only thing your regex contains, they'll match the same stuff. However, `.*(?=\d)` would be a more correct expression, unless there's more to it than what you put in the question.

Where it really matters is when you're using *capturing groups* or where you're using the content of the matched text after running the regular expression:

If you want to capture all text before the number, but not the number itself, and use it after, you could do this:

```
(.*?(?=\d))
```

The `?` makes the match non-greedy, so it will only match up to the first number. All text leading up to the number will be in the match result as the first group.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the difference below
In detail

.*   means matches any character (except newline)
(?=\d) means Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
\d match a digit [0-9]

(?=.*\d)

```
CapturingGroup
```

MatchOnlyIfFollowedBy
   Sequence: match all of the followings in order
   Repeat
   AnyCharacterExcept\n
   zero or more times
   Digit

.*(?=\d)

Sequence: match all of the followings in order
Repeat
AnyCharacterExcept\n
zero or more times
CapturingGroup
MatchOnlyIfFollowedBy
Digit

Comment: Please find few regular expression parser/decoder  just for reference
http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws
https://regex101.com/